# How to migrate global stylesheet to GSS in GWT

Tags: gwt

I have a GWT 2.7 application where a lot of the styling is done in a CSS file referenced in the module XML file. I'd like to migrate this file to GSS so I can use some of the new functionality like variables and functions.

The [GSS Migration Guide](http://www.gwtproject.org/articles/gss_migration.html) has instructions on migrating to GSS, but it appears to apply only to styles used through CSSResource objects. My understanding is that the only class selectors that can be accessed through CSSResources are those for which one declares accessors, and that all these class selectors will be obfuscated. This won't work for me because the selectors I want to use are unobfuscated ones that have mainly been added through `UIObject.addStyleName` and `addStyleDependentName`. I also don't want to have to add an accessor to an interface every time I want to add a new style.

As for the [other three ways](http://www.gwtproject.org/doc/latest/DevGuideUiCss.html#cssfiles) of using CSS files in a GWT project:

- Using a `<link>` tag in the host HTML page.
- Using the `<stylesheet>` element in the module XML file.
- Using an inline `<ui:style>` element in a UiBinder template.

The first two don't seem to support GSS: even if I specify a GSS file it simply gets served directly to the browser without processing.

Is my only choice, then, to migrate to UIBinder? And if so, what's the minimal way to do this? (My current HTML host page is just the [default host page](http://www.gwtproject.org/doc/latest/DevGuideOrganizingProjects.html#DevGuideHostPage) with some additional stuff in the `<head>` element, so I feel like this ought to be straightforward).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I discovered later on, it turns out that you *can* inject a GSS (or CSS) stylesheet as a `CSSResource` without the selectors being obfuscated. Simply add the following annotation to the stylesheet:

```
@external '*';
```

This will mark all selectors in the file as external, which means 1) that the `CSSResource` subinterface used as the type for the stylesheet resource will no longer be required to implement accessor methods corresponding corresponding to the class selectors in the stylesheet and 2) that the selectors in the stylesheet will be unobfuscated, so for example if you have a class `.foo` in the stylesheet you'll be able to apply it to entities using `UIObject.addStyleName("foo")`.

This way you can easily get some of the major benefits of GSS (variables, functions, etc.) and CSSResource (injection into the page rather than serving another file) without having to make any changes to your workflow.

Answer (score 1):

Using a `<ui:style>` is the same as using `CssResource`. The .ui.xml file will generate the required ClientBundle and CssResource files, and those in turn will convert the GSS to css.

When you refer to `<ui:style>` content in a .ui.xml file, you do so as if you were caling an accessor on the interface, as `{style.myStyleName}` - because you are calling the accessor, but it is generated automatically. This may limit what you can do in your `<ui:style>` tag slightly. On the other hand, once you write CSS, your IDE can almost certainly add the accessors for you automatically, and if it doesn't, the failed recompile will list them so you can add them.

If instead you simply put a string literal "my-class-name" in your Java or HTML, the compiler has no way of knowing that "my-class-name" is the same or different everywhere in your app, and when to use one CssResource versus another. It also cannot rewrite those strings, so your CSS would remain unoptimized. Plus, now you can check for usages of a given css class name accessor - if no one uses it, delete it, then delete the CSS that uses it, to keep your .gss files smaller, and your application smaller.

---

You are correct in that `<link>` tags in the html, and `<stylesheet>` tags in the .gwt.xml do not result in running GSS. You *do not* need to use UiBinder (and I'm not a fan personally, but some people like it), but you do need to use the accessors, or there is no point to GSS as it stands.

If you want to avoid obfuscation and renaming, consider just running the closure-stylesheets directly, or something like LESS or SASS on your plain CSS file, which have no GWT integration, and so will work just fine with your string literals already in use. This will result in bigger compiled outputs, and remove your ability to find and remove unused CSS in an easy way.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer! That makes a lot of sense. I guess I'll stick with bringing CSS in through a `<stylesheet>` tag in XML. I have to say this leaves me a bit disappointed/puzzled by the direction styling is going in GWT: I get that `<ui:style>` and `CSSResource` have various benefits, but make for more complicated and designer-unfriendly workflows. Also, it seems weird that `<link>` and `<stylesheet>` are deprecated but `UIObject.addStyleName` etc. are not...

Comment: The HTML tag `<link>` is deprecated? I think you're mistaken. I'm also not sure about `<stylesheet>` being deprecated. W.r.t. workflows, they are what you make them - compile with cssresource.style=pretty and you can export easy to read/write html and gss (regular command line closure stylesheet compiler), or if your designers can't handle gss anyway, I'm not sure why you'd be even trying GSS ("so I can use some of the new functionality"). I do encourage you to explore the tool a bit more before writing it off, esp if your designers want those vars/functions. Otherwise: LESS/SASS/plain-css.

Comment: I read that `<link>` and `<stylesheet>` are deprecated in [the documentation](http://www.gwtproject.org/doc/latest/DevGuideUiCss.html#cssfiles), but it wouldn't be the first time the docs gave me the wrong impression about something. As for workflows, sorry, I misspoke and it's more the coding (in response to designers) workflow I dislike: the `UIObject.addStyleName` etc provide a nice way of gradually styling an application first built with vanilla GWT aesthetics, and I don't see an analogous way of doing that with `CSSResource`. In any case LESS/SASS should suit my needs as you suggest.

Comment: Haha, fair point. It is poorly worded, let me try to help. As I understand it, there are two facets: Using raw CSS is as "deprecated" as raw JS is, since we have powerful optimizing compilers - by using plain CSS you have to do the compiler's work, by hand. Second, the `public/` directory should be avoided as there are almost better ways to do it - and two modules in the same app each with a in their own `public/` dir will clobber each other! That sounds more like the bad old days of plain JS than we'd like from GWT...